# How to get "event logs" similar to "remix"?

Tags: web3js, remix, contract-invocation, events, logs

I have an event as follows :

```
event LogNewObject(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, bytes32 sub_states_types, bytes32 sub_states_values, address owner);
```

And this event is used in following function :

```
function newObject(bytes32 _id, uint256 number_of_sub_states, bytes32[10] sub_states_types, bytes32[10] sub_states_values, address _owner) public returns(bool success) {
        require(!isObject(_id));

        uint256 counter=0;
        for(counter; counter < number_of_sub_states; counter++) {

            objectStructs[_id].state.sub_state[sub_states_types[counter]] = sub_states_values[counter];

            emit LogNewObject(msg.sender, _id, bytes32(sub_states_types[counter]), bytes32(sub_states_values[counter]), _owner);

        }

        objectStructs[_id].owner = _owner;
        objectStructs[_id].isObject = true;

        objectList.push(_id);

        return true;
    }
```

I want to get the logs like **remix** as following picture shows :

[image]

However, when I use following code to get event logs :

```
var Ev = contractInstance.LogNewObject({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
       Ev.get((error, events) => {
       if (!error) {
          function ShowResults(event) {
            console.log('sub_states_types: ' + event.args.sub_states_types);
            console.log('sub_states_values: ' + event.args.sub_states_values);
            }
          events.forEach(ShowResults);
        } else {
        console.log('Error');
          }
        });
```

I receive following error :

**TypeError: contractInstance.LogNewObject is not a function**

How can I call `event LogNewObject` to get the result like **remix logs output** as the above picture shows?

NOTE: I modified my commands according to the answer of User "oktapodia". the first spep is now free of errror, however I receive another error as follows :

```
> var Ev = contractInstance.events.LogNewObject({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
undefined
>        Ev.events.get((error, events) => {
...        if (!error) {
.....           function ShowResults(event) {
.......             console.log('sub_states_types: ' + event.args.sub_states_types);
.......             console.log('sub_states_values: ' + event.args.sub_states_values);
.......             }
.....           events.forEach(ShowResults);
.....         } else {
.....         console.log('Error');
.....           }
...         });
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

And if I use the following format, I receive again previous error :

```
> var Ev = contractInstance.events.LogNewObject({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
undefined
>        Ev.get((error, events) => {
...        if (!error) {
.....           function ShowResults(event) {
.......             console.log('sub_states_types: ' + event.args.sub_states_types);
.......             console.log('sub_states_values: ' + event.args.sub_states_values);
.......             }
.....           events.forEach(ShowResults);
.....         } else {
.....         console.log('Error');
.....           }
...         });
TypeError: Ev.get is not a functionI also used the command proposed by user "oktapodia", however I receive this error :
```

[image]

I also used the command as user "oktapodia" is explained in his answer. However I receive a new error as follows : **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'LogNewObject' of undefined"**

[image]

**Important Note: Here is my smart contract code** :

```
pragma solidity 0.4.23; 

contract RFID {

    struct StateStruct {
        bytes32 description;
        mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) sub_state;
    }

    struct ObjectStruct {
        StateStruct state;
        address owner; 
        bool isObject;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => ObjectStruct) objectStructs;
    bytes32[] public objectList;

    event LogNewObject(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, bytes32 sub_states_types, bytes32 sub_states_values, address owner);
    event LogChangeObjectState(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, bytes32 sub_states_types, bytes32 sub_states_values);
    event LogChangeObjectOwner(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, address newOwner);

    function isObject(bytes32 _id) public view returns(bool isIndeed) {
        return objectStructs[_id].isObject;
    }

    function getObjectCount() public view returns(uint count) {
        return objectList.length;
    }

    /*function setArraySize(uint256 _number_of_sub_states) public {

        number_of_sub_states = _number_of_sub_states;

    }

    function getArraySize() view public returns (uint256) {
       return number_of_sub_states;
    }*/

    function newObject(bytes32 _id, uint256 number_of_sub_states, bytes32[10] sub_states_types, bytes32[10] sub_states_values, address _owner) public returns(bool success) {
        require(!isObject(_id));

        uint256 counter=0;
        for(counter; counter < number_of_sub_states; counter++) {

            objectStructs[_id].state.sub_state[sub_states_types[counter]] = sub_states_values[counter];

            emit LogNewObject(msg.sender, _id, bytes32(sub_states_types[counter]), bytes32(sub_states_values[counter]), _owner);

        }

        objectStructs[_id].owner = _owner;
        objectStructs[_id].isObject = true;

        objectList.push(_id);

        return true;
    }

    function changeObjectState(bytes32 _id, uint256 number_of_sub_states, bytes32[10] sub_states_types, bytes32[10] sub_states_values) public returns(bool success) {
        require(isObject(_id));
        uint256 counter=0;
        for(counter; counter < number_of_sub_states; counter++) {

            objectStructs[_id].state.sub_state[sub_states_types[counter]] = sub_states_values[counter];

            emit LogChangeObjectState(msg.sender, _id, bytes32(sub_states_types[counter]), bytes32(sub_states_values[counter]));

        }
        //objectStructs[_id].state = StateStruct(_newState);
        //emit LogChangeObjectState(msg.sender, _id, _newState);
        return true;
    }

    function changeObjectOwner(bytes32 _id, address _newOwner) public returns(bool success) {
        require(isObject(_id));
        objectStructs[_id].owner = _newOwner;
        emit LogChangeObjectOwner(msg.sender, _id, _newOwner);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And to invoke `function newObject` using following command :

```
contractInstance.methods.newObject(web3.utils.asciiToHex("50"),3,[web3.utils.asciiToHex("location"),web3.utils.asciiToHex("price"),web3.utils.asciiToHex("sold"),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex("")],[web3.utils.asciiToHex("Paris"),web3.utils.asciiToHex("50"),web3.utils.asciiToHex("No"),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex("")], '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773').send({ from: '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773' }, function(error, result) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(result)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using the version 1.0 of web3 with the new syntax ([doc here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events))

Change `contractInstance.LogNewObject` to `contractInstance.events.LogNewObject`

Comment: Thank you. however, I receive another error. I explained it in mu question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is too long to add it in a single comment.

Because you are running it directly in your terminal and not from a file, in NodeJS the semicolon is not a mandatory and your terminal interpret the `.on` as a new line in a new scope and not a function bind to `contractInstance.events.LogNewObject`, the following example should work directly from your terminal, but not really beautiful :)

```
contractInstance.events.LogNewObject({
  fromBlock: 0,
}, function(error, event){ console.log(event); }).on('data', function(event){
    console.log(event); // same results as the optional callback above
  }).on('changed', function(event){
    // remove event from local database
  }).on('error', console.error);
```

Comment: I receive another error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'LogNewObject' of undefined". I put its screen shot in my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure that you are still using `web3@^1.0`, you are still have the `event LogNewObject` in your smart contract and your ABI is the latest one?

Comment: Yes, I got web3 version and here is the output: "web3.version
'1.0.0-beta.34'". And I also run my contract with both remix and command line web3js successfully, i mean its abi did not changed.

Comment: Are you sure about the case? or the contract address?

Comment: Yes, I did a transaction right now. You can see the result here : https://ibb.co/kDyfM7

Comment: I added code of my smart contract to my question.

Comment: Can you add also the `addNewObject` arguments please? I'm gonna check locally (in text please ;) )

Comment: Do you mean `"LogNewObject"` ? There is not `addNewObject` in mycontract. we have only `function newObject` and `event LogNewObject`.

Comment: `newObject` sorry

Comment: where exactly I should add `newObject` parameter ? its parameters are `function newObject(bytes32 _id, uint256 number_of_sub_states, bytes32[10] sub_states_types, bytes32[10] sub_states_values, address _owner)` Thanks.

Comment: I mean the second command you entered, https://ibb.co/kDyfM7 I don't want to recopy it by myself tbh ^^

Comment: I added how to invoke `function newObject` to my question.  I hope this is what you expect. Do you think how to get an output like `remix` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a get like that with the web3 api, according to [the doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events) and use the event emitter or a callback:

example:

```
contractInstance.events.LogNewObject({
    fromBlock: 0,
}, function(error, event){ console.log(event); }) // callback here
.on('data', function(event){
    console.log(event); // same results as the optional callback above
})
.on('changed', function(event){
    // remove event from local database
})
.on('error', console.error);

// event output example
> {
    returnValues: {
        myIndexedParam: 20,
        myOtherIndexedParam: '0x123456789...',
        myNonIndexParam: 'My String'
    },
    raw: {
        data: '0x7f9fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead79fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91385',
        topics: ['0xfd43ade1c09fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91ffdd57a7af66ab4ead7', '0x7f9fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead79fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91385']
    },
    event: 'MyEvent',
    signature: '0xfd43ade1c09fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91ffdd57a7af66ab4ead7',
    logIndex: 0,
    transactionIndex: 0,
    transactionHash: '0x7f9fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead79fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91385',
    blockHash: '0xfd43ade1c09fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91ffdd57a7af66ab4ead7',
    blockNumber: 1234,
    address: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please let me know how did you use your command? because, when i use your command, i receive the error that I put its screen shot in my question. Thanks